# Why is my image lifted outside of its own dimensions by about 1px?

Tags: image

I am trying to place a circular image into a button using the following styles and HTML:

```
.team-assign-pic {height: 32px; width: 32px}

<button class="team-assign" type="button">
    <img alt="image" class="team-assign-pic" src="img/a1.jpg">&nbsp; Treavor M.
</button>
```

What is happening is that the image is constrained to its 32x32 pixel shape, but it's actually getting "lifted" up by what looks like 1px above its own positioning so it's true size on the page would be something like:

```
{height: 33px; width: 32px}
```

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tng8n.png)

This is a bit tricky for me to verbally explain so I've attached an image - its subtle, but it's driving me crazy!

How do I keep it from "lifting" above its own size and position?

Comment: Where is the image you attached?

Comment: It didn't attach correctly the first time through so I had to create a link to it. Click on "Screenshot of the issue" to open it. Thanks!

Comment: What css properties are applied on your `img`? I'm wondering if something there is affecting it.